# How to reload an img without showing broken image on errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to find a way where I can reload an image every second-or-so... and if the image fails to load once (either due to a 404 error, or some other similar error)... not show a broken image until the next time it reloads.  I have considered having a hidden  that does the load-attempts, and if the load is successful, update the displayed image.  This seems very cludgy.  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: ajax - test if status code == 200 and then show the image

Comment: @bksl, would you care to expand on that idea?  Are you suggesting dumping binary data into the img object?

Comment: Did you used ajax?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

Comment: I would recommend looking into "ajax" and "javascript preloading images".  jQuery makes it very easy to create ajax requests.  Also, when asking for help on SO, please reduce your post down to a specific problem.  Rather than "how do I build X application", try to build a solution until you run into a error or clearly definable and reproducible problem; and post about that specific issue.

Comment: @bksi sadly, this does not use ajax or jquery.  It doesn't even load the img data.  That is only useful for http or text content.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I have done quite a bit of looking... the problem is that jquery doesn't handle binary data very well... and most solutions require xhr.... and a lot more cludging.

Comment: ajax is clunky for this. let browser do it using an image preloader and only update if `onload` succeeds

Answer (score -2):

Try [`onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/image#a-onerror).

You can pass a function to it and handle the image load failure.

Comment: According to W3, img objects aren't supposed to have an onerror event... and secondly, if the onerror fires... the image is already replaced with the broken image icon.

Comment: @TheCompWiz According to Mozilla Developer Network, onerror is a valid event for image elements. I have created a fiddle for you to test https://jsfiddle.net/thbp94/q3e29p58/. Image is fixed with correct image.

Comment: You failed to understand the issue.  I don't need to load another image on error... I want the current image to not be replaced with the broken icon... but rather keep the previously loaded image.